# Pinot - Converting a String to traversable JSON

Tags: json, string, apache-pinot, pinot

I've got a string coming in from a Kafka stream that looks a lot like the Usage Example of the [JSONFORMAT](https://docs.pinot.apache.org/configuration-reference/functions/jsonformat) documentation.

What I'm struggling with now is how to convert it into a *traversable* JSON, such that I can, in the example from the documentation, put the "age" value into a column in my table.

I've tried the following:

`jsonPath(JSONFORMAT(meta), '$.age')"`

`jsonPath(TOJSONMAPSTR(meta), '$.age')"`

which are combinations of the JSONFORMAT and jsonPath functions.

I've validated that the `jsonPath` function works as expected when the data from my Kafka stream is actually formatted as a JSON, i.e. `"jsonPath(source, '$.init_sync_state')"`, so I'm not suspecting that to be the root cause of my troubles.

I'd expect this combination of functions to first convert my string into a JSON, and then extract the value from the specific path. However, it seems that JSONFORMAT isn't actually converting the data into a JSON. I've also tried [TOJSONMAPSTR](https://docs.pinot.apache.org/configuration-reference/functions/tojsonmapstr) but it yielded the same result.

Is there a way to convert a string into JSON structure in Pinot? Am I missing something obvious?

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Solved:

The solution was to use a [jsonIndex](https://docs.pinot.apache.org/basics/indexing/json-index#how-to-use-json-index) which flattens out the JSON into a `STRING` column, and then use `jsonPath` to access it.

I.e. in the example from above, we'd do:

```
"jsonIndexConfigs": {
   "meta": {
       "maxLevels": 1,
       "excludeArray": false,
       "disableCrossArrayUnnest": true,
       "includePaths": null,
       "excludePaths": null,
       "excludeFields": null
       }
}
```

and then insert age into my column using a transformation column that looks like this:

```
{
   "columnName": "age",
   "transformFunction": "jsonPath(document, '$.age')"
},
```

Answer (score 0):

One more thing to add here is to set the `maxLength` field in data schema for the string column. (Ref: https://docs.pinot.apache.org/configuration-reference/schema#advanced-fields)

This is to ensure pinot indexes the full json string, otherwise the string might be truncated and the json function will fail for parsing error.